# How to get access to handler id from Gtk.Builder.connect_signals

Tags: python, gtk, glade

I have a Glade file with some buttons and I use `Gtk.Builder.connect_signals()` to connect methods (`on_button_toggled`) with the corresponding signals (`toggled`). 
(It is acutally [quickly](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/tools/quickly/) which does that for me, but I can see and change that code, so that is only a detail).

What I want to do now, is stop a signal from being processed, e.g. though a call to `object.handler_block(handler_id)` or `object.disconnect(handler_id)`. So my question is: how can I get the `handler_id`s for connections created via `Gtk.Builder.connect_signals()`?

Normally you would get the `handler_id` from a call to one of:

```
handler_id = object.connect(name, cb, cb_args)  
handler_id = object.connect_after(name, cb, cb_args)
handler_id = object.connect_object(name, cb, slot_object, cb_args)  
handler_id = object.connect_object_after(name, cb, slot_object, cb_args)
```

but the Gtk.Builder version does not return the ids.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, I don't believe that there's any way to get at the signal handler IDs that were connected by `Gtk.Builder`. If you really want the handlers, you have to manually connect your signals, storing any `handler_id`s you care about.

An alternative approach is to decide that you don't actually need the handlers themselves, but can block/unblock/etc. based on the connected callable, using `GObject.handler_block_by_func` and similar.

The final option is to try to actually find the handler after the fact, using as many details as you can. In C, use `g_signal_handler_find`; this isn't bound for pygtk2, but presumably will work using pygobject3. The downside here is that there's no guarantee that you'll find what you *actually* connected.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably too late for you but I have a solution to get the name of the widget you clicked that is set up with...

```
self.builder.connect_signals(self)
```

From [this source](http://gnipsel.com/glade/gtk11b.html), the author uses gtk.Buildable.get_name() to get the name of the widget/object.  In my scenario, depending on what button was clicked a different action occurred.  I wanted to attach the same event handler to all of the buttons of a certain type, because they largely do the same thing.  Here's the code.

```
import gtk

class GUI:
  def __init__(self):
    self.builder = gtk.Builder()
    self.builder.add_from_file('myGUI.glade')
    self.builder.connect_signals(self)
    self.window = self.builder.get_object("window1")
    self.window.show()

  def on_button_click(self, object, data=None):
    print(gtk.Buildable.get_name(object))
```

Pretty cool, eh?  I think so, at least.

Answer (score 2):

With PyGObject, the best way is the `signal_handler_find` approach I think. Use this function, which uses two functions from GObject

```
def get_handler_id(obj, signal_name):
    signal_id, detail = GObject.signal_parse_name(signal_name, obj, True)
    return GObject.signal_handler_find(obj, GObject.SignalMatchType.ID, signal_id, detail, None, None, None)
```

Usage example:

```
get_handler_id(button, "clicked")
```

will get you the `handler_id` for a handler connected to the `clicked` signal of `button`. This can then be used for `handler_block`.